# typescript compiler issue for @types/applicationinsights-js

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-application-insights, tsc

I have an angular application using Microsoft applicationinsights-js. Somehow tsc -p command gives an issue while converting this to javascript. Is it due to incompatible versions of typescript and applicationinsights? Below is the error message we get:

> @types/applicationinsights-js/index.d.ts:424:40 - error TS2304: 
>           Cannot find name 'PerformanceTiming'.
>
> ```
>     static getPerformanceTiming(): PerformanceTiming;
> ```

I appreciate any help in this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. `PerformanceTiming` is a common web interface, as described at [Mozilla Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming). You need to add `"lib": ["dom"]` in `compilerOptions`property at `tsconfig.json` file.